How to Change file name when it's uploaded?
How do I rename an image after uploading it?
Random letters or numbers
example: abcd or 123456
I figured that it would be easy enough to change the html attribute in javascript rather than playing with Sharepoint backend. So that when I upload a file it changes the name of the file (not the data)
<?php
    $currentDirectory = getcwd();
    $uploadDirectory = "/uploads/";

    $errors = []; // Store errors here

    $fileExtensionsAllowed = ['jpeg','jpg','png'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['the_file']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['the_file']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['the_file']['type'];
    $tmp = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileExtension = end($tmp);

    $uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensionsAllowed)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file";
      }

      if ($fileSize > 4000000) {
        $errors[] = "File exceeds maximum size (4MB)";
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
          echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
          echo "An error occurred. Please contact the administrator.";
        }
      } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
          echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
      }

    }
?>

Thank You Very Much!...

The second parameter of move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath); is the destination of the uploaded file with also includes it's filename.
You only need to change the $uploadPath variable to contain the random name you want.
Ex:
$uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . uniqid() . '.' . $fileExtension; 


This code: echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
Please tell me how to output the name with numbers + letters.
example: 663c73f32ca54.jpg, 663c74aaf39d5.png

@Y.EY, you can use a function, like uniqid() that I posted in my answer, but it doesn't guarantee uniqueness—be careful. I recommend that you create a variable like $destFileName = uniqid() . '.' . $fileExtension and change $uploadPath = $currentDirectory . $uploadDirectory . $destFileName. Now, you just need to change the string to "The file " . $destFileName . " has been uploaded".
